# Incorrect text layout in android xml

Tags: android

I am having issues with my layout in android. Basically my text is displayed in a line like so:

**@string/no @string/day_mainpage @string/no**

However, I want the text **@string/day_mainpage @string/no** to be displayed underneath the the first **@string/no** so that it's like so:

```
           @string/no 
@string/day_mainpage @string/no
```

How can the xml be changed to meet this requirement?

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.example.tecocraft.challenge_reward.widget.ButtonTextViewBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black_dark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <com.example.tecocraft.challenge_reward.widget.ButtonTextViewBold
                android:id="@+id/main_page_no1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="@string/no"
                android:textColor="@color/black_dark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.example.tecocraft.challenge_reward.widget.ButtonTextViewBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/day_mainpage"
                android:textColor="@color/black_dark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.example.tecocraft.challenge_reward.widget.ButtonTextViewBold
                android:id="@+id/main_page_no2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="@string/no"
                android:textColor="@color/black_dark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change the outermost `<LinearLayout>`'s `orientation` to `vertical`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your parent layout has an horizontal orientation: every child view is displayed in a column. LinearLayout is a view group that aligns all children in a single direction, vertically or horizontally.

So, as said in the comment, simply change the outermost LinearLayout's orientation to vertical

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"> <-- This one
...
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

You can learn more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout).